# “ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python.” when installing simple audio for Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, pyaudio, windowserror

I tried to install the `simpleaudio` module but I keep getting the same error. In my previous attempts, I included in the installation of python the path checkmark, and checked for pip to be installed on the PC.

I similarly tried to run both `python3 -m pip install simpleaudio` and `python -m pip install simpleaudio`, and only for python was the command executed but with the outputted error shown in the image:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO, please refrain from code in images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the picture

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required........
```

Looks like you need to install C++ to build the module

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that as the size of the installation files was quite big. I'll try to do that and get back with an answer.

Comment: Would you consider accepting the answer or upvoting please?

Answer (score 1):

This solution is specifically for linux user.

You need to install ***libasound2-dev*** at first. Then you can install simpleaudio.

1. `sudo apt-get install libasound2-dev`
2. `pip install simpleaudio`

Though this question is asked for windows, this process solves the problem for linux user.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem with out installing C++ library.

1. from here you can find it [simpleaudio](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#simpleaudio)
2. You can download wheel file according to your python version and
3. download it and give full path of that file and install it as like mine is `python 3.9` with `64bit`

`pip install simpleaudio‑1.0.4‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl`

Answer (score 0):

(Win10) I had the same problem.
Confirm that Bhavya Parikh solution works.

cmd open as admin
change direction to folder where You get file a than:

```sh
pip install simpleaudio‑1.0.4‑cp39‑cp39‑win_amd64.whl
```